# To Lay A Hit, Blow

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang, word-usage

Is 'to lay a hit/blow on' someone (as in cheap shot) a slang expression?

Comment: Can you cite one of your sources to show more context?

Comment: (US native speaker) I've never heard 'to lay' but I have heard 'to land a blow/hit' although the latter doesn't imply a cheap shot. Slang for cheap shot would be something like 'a low blow' or 'a hit below the belt'

Answer (score 2):

There is a different idiom: *[lay waste to](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lay+waste+to)*.

The confusion between that and *[land a blow](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/land+a+blow)* is most likely what caused the question and also brought me here.

Answer (score 1):

The Corpus of Contemporary American English has one record for *lay a hit* and none for *lay a blow*. Neither is found in the British National Corpus. Of course, the expression may occur in other forms, such as *laid a hit*, but it seems unlikely that it is at all common. However, in British English, at least, *lay one on him* means to hit someone. Given the circumstances in which it is likely to be used, it will rarely if at all be found in formal writing, other than as part of a dialogue in fiction, perhaps.